# Problem with Laravel Eloquent - relation not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'am beginner in Laravel. I have project in Laravel 5.8.

I have `User` model:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    use psCMS\Presenters\UserPresenter;
    use scopeActiveTrait;

    public static $roles = [];
    public $dates = ['last_activity'];

    // ...    

    public function scopeHistory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserLoginHistory');
    }

    // ...
}
```

and `UserLoginHistory`:

```
class UserLoginHistory extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = ['id'];
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'date_time', 'ip'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

I want show user login history by this code:

```
User::history()->where('id', $idAdmin)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);
```

but it's not working.

This function not working - I haven't got results.

How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are defining your relationship as a scope (prefixing the relationship with the `scope` keyword). Try updating your model relationship to this:

```
public function history()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserLoginHistory');
}
```

Then, given your query, it seems that you want to get all the `UserLoginHistory` 
records for a given `User`. You could accomplish this in two ways (at least).

From the `UserLoginHistory` model itself, constraining the query by the foreign key value:

```
$userId = auth()->id(); // get the user ID here.

$results = UserLoginHistory::where('user_id', $userId)->paginate(15);
//                                  ^^^^^^^ your FK column name
```

From the `User` model using your defined relationship:

```
$userId = auth()->id(); // get the user ID here.

$results = User::find($userId)->history;
```

The downside of the second approach is that you'll need to paginate the results manually.

Answer (score 1):

in your User model you should define your relation by this way :

```
public function history()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserLoginHistory');
    }
```

then if you would like to select with history model you can do that with **WhereHas()** method :

```
User::whereHas(['history'=>function($q) use ($idAdmin) {
    $q->where('id',$idAdmin)
}])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be do this changes

```
public function history()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserLoginHistory');
}
```

usage

```
$user = User::find($idAdmin);
$userHistories = $user->history()->latest()->paginate(25);
```

or get user with all history

```
User::with('history')->find($idAdmin);
```

Comment: This return: Non-static method App\User::history() should not be called statically

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Post model 

    namespace App;
    use App\User;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Post extends Model
    {
         public function categories()
        {
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
        }
    }


    // Category model 


    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Category extends Model
    {
            public function posts()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post')->withTimestamps();
        }
    }
```